# Android Loopj AndroidAsyncHttp mocking

Tags: android, json, mocking, response

is there are any way to mock [Loopj AndroidAsyncHttp](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) responses? 
I am developing application which depends on REST API, but API is not ready yet and I want to develop application independently from API. Retrofit has a lot of mock implementations, but I was not able to find any solutions for `AndroidAsyncHttp`. Is there are any way? 
I tried to send success message to handler on request creation `handler.sendSuccessMessage(200, new Header[1], new byte[1]);` , but `onSuccess` or something else is not called.

Answer (score 0):

As example, you may create on any hosting php file with responsing json. 
Or you can use my template for this cases http://so.five-dots.ru/api-test.php

Make responsing on this address and implements your logic. Then RESTfull API backend service will be ready, you can replace adresses on real and getting responseBody will reqirement data.